# Neyman-Pearson method for model selection

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, model-selection, neyman-pearson-lemma

I am studying about the competing model fittings, i.e., selection of one model. How can the Neyman-Pearson method be used for model selection in general?

Comment: The NP lemma is about hypothesis tests not model selection..Akaike Information Criterion or Bayes Information Criterion are used for model selection.

Comment: And make it clear: are you speaking of selecting the model family or selecting terms to include in the model?  Both create model uncertainty that hurts much of the inference.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - selecting model family. I was just trying to develop (a variant?) to see if NP lemma can be used to select one model over the other. In particular, i thought of assigning models to hypothesis (H0 and H1) and reject accordingly. (this is just an idea, i might be totally wrong.) I wanted to know if I am thinking in the right direction

Comment: The problem is that if one model is nested in the other or one has more parameters, then the larger model will usually win in a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: AIC is meant for this situation.